# The position of if __name__ == "__main__":

Tags: python

I am learning `main` and explore its applications with codes:

```
a = 1
b = 2

def main():
    x = add(a, b)
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

def add(a, b):
    a = a + 1
    return a + b
```

However, it report NameError:

```
In [87]: run test.py                                                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError   Traceback (most recent call last)

NameError: name 'add' is not defined
```

Re-position `if __name__ == "__main__":`  to end is a solution,

```
a = 1
b = 2

def main():
    x = add(a, b)
    print(x)

def add(a, b):
    a = a + 1
    return a + b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
In [88]: run test.py                                                                                              
4
```

I am confused about why the previous case failed.

`if __name__ == "__main__":` invoke `main`, `main` invoke add.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sugvnHA7ElY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything is done in order in Python, top to bottom.

```
a = 1  # assigns 1 -> a
b = 2  # assigns 2 -> b

def main():  # main is defined
    # body of main, not executed until it's called.

if __name__ == "__main__":  # it does! Let's enter the block
    main()  # let's run main, so we have to look back at that block we skipped earlier...

    # from above
    x = add(a, b)  # call add....oh wait -- WHAT'S add?!
```

In the bottom example, `add` is defined before `main` is executed, so `main` knows what to do when you call `x = add(a, b)`.

Comment: so if there's a executing line, codes after it will be ignored?

Comment: The line of execution runs top to bottom. When it hits the line that calls main, it executes the code in `main`'s function body. That code calls `add`, but in your top example, the line of execution hasn't gotten to the definition of `add` yet (because it's below the call to `main`) so `main` has no way to know what `add` is.

Comment: ty, I got it.  invoke add(a, b), ahead of define it.

Answer (score 5):

Python effectively runs lines of code as it reads them from the file. (Not really, but for purposes of this question, it acts as if it does.) So when this piece of code runs:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

in your first code sample, the `add` function has not yet been defined. That only happens when Python encounters the `def add(...):` block. Since `main()` calls `add()`, Python complains that an undefined name (`add`) is being used.

When you move the `def add(...):` block up before the call to `main()`, then the definition of `add()` happens before `main()` runs, so everything is fine.